# How do I install Team Foundation Server 2008 on Windows XP?

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to install MS Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server in XP but during the installation the setup request Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1.I have install TFS 2008 SP1, but nothing have change.

I can't install Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 because  the OS is in XP.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server requires Windows Server 2003 with SP1 or Windows Server 2008. See [requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b0155166-b0a3-436e-ac95-37d7e39a440c&displaylang=en#Requirements).

Team Explorer and Team Foundation Build can be installed on XP with SP2.